# iOS Collection View Change Cell content on didSelectItemAt indexPath

Tags: uicollectionview, func, collectionview, indexpath

I need to access to the particular cell and change its content dynamically on didSelectAt indexPath

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
    didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == self.trendHeaderView{
            print(indexPath.row)
            // Needs to access cell and change the 
            // content of cell i.e label text inside cell ??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to access to the particular cell

No, you don't. You should *never* meddle with a cell's contents directly. You need to access the *data* (the "model") that the collection view's data source is using. And you can easily do that, because you have the `indexPath`. Change the *data*, and reload the collection view so that it picks up the changes and displays them.

Comment: Consider a case I have a view inside cell and label, and I have to change the nested view background then how can I do that ??

Comment: Do just what I said in my answer. Make the info about what the "nested view background" should be part of the _data_ (the model). In other words, encode all info needed into the model, and then have your `cellForItemAt:` take care of the configuration based on that info. That is what it _means_ to have a data source. No other approach can possibly work, not least because cells are reused in different item slots.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the cell's content directly in didSelectItemAt.
As you can see, in UICollectionView  cell is reused by calling dequeReusableCell.

So I think, it's good to make model for that.
and change the model content in didSelectItemAt.
and Please call reloadData to redraw collectionview.